# Changing SVN Repos (remote) keeping working copy changes

Tags: svn, version-control

I have an SVN repo at https://abc.xyz/myrepo. I hit some limits with this provider and decided to make my own SVN server/repo at https://myown.xyz/myrepo.

Since I hit the limits when I attempt to commit my pending changes... my working copy is ahead of my old repo (and unable to finish commit) and my new one is currently blank, at revision zero.

What's the easiest way to move my working copy to the new server? I have tortoiseSVN available, if that helps. I don't necessarily care about history (aka a nuke and commit WC as revision 1 would be ok).

I tried to do the relocate, but it errors complaining that my WC uid doesn't match the one from the new server.

I've been in git land for too long and while I know these are not always analogous to each other, I'm looking for the SVN version of adding a new remote so I can push to that one, removing my old remote thereafter. (again, don't necessarily care about history at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get UUID of your old repo (`svn info`)
2. Set UUID of your local repo with [`svnadmin setuuid`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html)
3. Relocate WC

Better solution: dump old /restore in new repo in the middle of process